# Django different forms for admin model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-mptt

Is there any way to load different admin forms for editing an objects depending of what object is needed to be updated?

For example - we have an `MPTTModelAdmin` objects. And for root objects we don't want to see some fields:

```
class RootObjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        exclude = ('title',)


class ChildObjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'birth_date')
```

But I don't know how to get object fields in forms.py or admin.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can always supply your own form class for a ModelAdmin class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

From there you can access fields by key, just like any other Django form:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # access whatever field by key
        # self.fields['field-name']
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand something, but the folowing code:    
from django.forms import ModelForm  
from mptt_test.models import Category  
  
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Category  
  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super(CategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        print self.fields['title']
prints:  
_<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f3f0047ff90>_  
  
And if I try to access special standart MPTT fields, such as _level_ (self.fields['level']) - I geat a _KeyError_

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MPTT...does it have a Django admin form mixin or class your ModelAdmin should inherit from? That might explain the missing field.

Comment: In has mptt.forms.MPTTAdminForm...  But class CategoryForm(MPTTAdminForm) doesn't work to. it still prints  _<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f6d804aeed0>_

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, I'm out of time to help on S.O. today, but I'm sure someone will know why you can't access those fields specific to the MPTT model.

Answer (score 0):

In forms.py file you can get object fields and their value at two stages.

1 : when form is submitted.
clean method does initial validations.

```
def clean(self):
    """ validation of address form """
    cleaned_data = super(WebsiteAddressForm, self).clean()
    field1_value = self.cleaned_data.get("field1")
    print field1_value
    return cleaned_data
```

2 : when form is initialized. ____init____ method will call.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.fields['field1']
```

Comment: Do this... but _print self.fields['title']_ prints: _<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f6d804aeed0>_

Comment: that was only for giving you a idea . in ____init____ you can initialize value of any field .  
self.fields['field1'] = "Hi this is default value "

Comment: I see... but is there some way to get field values when we just come  to page for update existed object ?  
For example - if some _news_ contains "some_field" and it's value already set to "1" - in admin edit form don't show some fileds of this news. In other case - show this fields

Comment: i can do this by _js_, but this isn't be a good practice, I guess

Comment: Sure you can .  but sometime server side handling is good way to manage form related things.